# How to build a global timer that appears in all app screens

Tags: android, global-variables, chronometer

I want to build a global timer with a value increments and appear across all app activities using Chronometer ,how to make the Chronometer value  global to all app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entire code solution but basic idea i can give you and this is how i implemented.

In BaseActivity or in Application class you can take the static timer in my case i have taken in BasActivity.

```
public static CountDownTimer timerBase;
private long startTimer;
```

Now on particular action this is how you can start the timer.

```
    public void sessionStart() {

        if (timerBase != null)
            timerBase.cancel();
          start = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
        timerBase = new CountDownTimer("Pass Total time the task should be excute", 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                long time = ("Pass Total time the task should be excute"/ 1000 - Math.round((float) millisUntilFinished / 1000.0f));
                String timeTakenForeachQue = String.valueOf(time);
                Log.e("counterValue", timeTakenForeachQue + " start = " + (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - start) / 1000 + " time " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
               // Do stuff when time finish

                Toast.makeText(BaseActivity.this,"time finished" Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }.start();
    }

}
```

Now you can access this method in any class as it is BaseActivity or in Application class.Also this is just basic idea how to implement as entire task not possible to publish.

Comment: let me know if still any help needed or stuck also upvote if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Use static method to initialize getInstance and retrieve values getFormatedTime().

```
public class CounterClass  extends CountDownTimer{

private static String hms;
private static CounterClass instance;

private CounterClass(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval){
    super(millisInFuture,countDownInterval);
}

public static CounterClass  initInstance(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval){
    if(instance==null){
        instance =  new CounterClass(millisInFuture,countDownInterval);
    }
    return instance;
}

public static CounterClass  getInstance() throws Exception{
    if(instance==null){
        throw new Exception("Parameters not initialized. Initiate with initInstance");
    }else{
        return instance;
    }
}

public static String getFormatedTime(){
    return hms;
}
@Override
public void onTick(long l) {

    long millis= l;
    hms= String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis))
    );
}
@Override
public void onFinish() {

}
}
```

I have modified the code.

Inorder to initiate the CounterClass, do the following.

```
CounterClass counterClass = CounterClass.initInstance(180000, 1000);
counterClass.start();
```

For accessing the previous value

```
try {
      CounterClass counterClass = CounterClass.getInstance();
      Log.i("TAG 222", counterClass.getFormatedTime());
     } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
       // counter class is not initiated , access initInstance
     }
```

As android.os.CountDownTimer does not have default constructor, this is the way we can achieve your requirement

Answer (score 1):

you can try this very easy

add this to xml

```
   <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout

                        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                        android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">

                        <Chronometer
                            android:id="@+id/simpleChronometer"
                            android:layout_width="125dp"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="end"
                            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textColor="@color/white" />

                                    <Button
                                        android:id="@+id/next"
                                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_weight="1"
                                        android:background="@color/green"
                                        android:gravity="center"
                                        android:text="@string/next"
                                        android:textColor="@color/white" />
                    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

add this to your firstActivity

```
public class firstActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    private Button Next;
    private Chronometer simpleChronometer;
    Long base, timeDeviceImages;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTheme(R.style.full_screen);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);

        Next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);

        simpleChronometer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.simpleChronometer);
        simpleChronometer.setOnChronometerTickListener(new Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer cArg) {
                long time = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - cArg.getBase();
                int h = (int) (time / 3600000);
                int m = (int) (time - h * 3600000) / 60000;
                int s = (int) (time - h * 3600000 - m * 60000) / 1000;
                String hh = h < 10 ? "0" + h : h + "";
                String mm = m < 10 ? "0" + m : m + "";
                String ss = s < 10 ? "0" + s : s + "";
                cArg.setText(hh + ":" + mm + ":" + ss);
            }
        });
        simpleChronometer.start();
        timeDeviceImages = simpleChronometer.getBase();

 Next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(firstActivity.this, UnitCondition.class);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("timerJob", String.valueOf(timeDeviceImages));
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

  }
}
```

and in another activity add this

```
public class secondActivity  extends AppCompatActivity  {
    private Chronometer simpleChronometer;
    Long base, timeDeviceImages;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTheme(R.style.full_screen);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);


        base = Long.valueOf(getIntent().getExtras().getString("timeUnit"));
        simpleChronometer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.simpleChronometer);
        simpleChronometer.setOnChronometerTickListener(new Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer cArg) {
                long time = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - cArg.getBase();
                int h = (int) (time / 3600000);
                int m = (int) (time - h * 3600000) / 60000;
                int s = (int) (time - h * 3600000 - m * 60000) / 1000;
                String hh = h < 10 ? "0" + h : h + "";
                String mm = m < 10 ? "0" + m : m + "";
                String ss = s < 10 ? "0" + s : s + "";
                cArg.setText(hh + ":" + mm + ":" + ss);
            }
        });
        simpleChronometer.setBase((base));
        simpleChronometer.start();
        timeDeviceImages = simpleChronometer.getBase();
 }
}
```